# Molecular Dynamics Simulations in VASP

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, ab-initio-calculations

I want to run molecular dynamics (MD) simulations with VASP for Mg2Si to investigate the simulation time vs `ENCUT` and `KPOINTS`, but I do not know how to set INCAR tags for example for the first run if `ENCUT` = 500 eV with 100fs time then should I change the value of `ENCUT` and time for the second run? What parameters of `INCAR` will remain the same to compare `ENCUT` with simulation time and to get one plot of energy convergence? If the first run goes well should I change my `POSCAR` too for the second run as input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### MD input card for H2O molecule:

```
 # General tags
 PREC   = Normal    
 ENCUT  = 400   
 ALGO   = Fast  
 LREAL  = Auto  
 ISMEAR = 0         # Gaussian smearing 
 SIGMA  = 0.05      
 ISYM   = 0         # Symmetry off  

 # MD related   
 IBRION = 0         # MD    
 POTIM  = 0.5       # Time step=0.5 fs
 NSW    = 100       # Number of ionic steps 
 TEBEG  = 400       # Start temperature         
 TEEND  = 400       # Final temperature     
 SMASS  = 0         # Canonical (Nose-Hoover) thermostat    
 POMASS = 16.0  2.0 # Deuterium mass for Hydrogen   

 # Don’t write WAVECAR or CHGCAR    
 LWAVE  = F     
 LCHARG = F
```

### KPOINTS card for H2O molecule:

```
 KPOINTS (Gamma-only)   
  0 
 Gamma  
 1  1   1   
 0  0   0
```

- Ref1: https://wiki.bnl.gov/CFN-Computation/images/3/3f/Tutorial6.pdf
- Ref2: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/H2O_molecular_dynamics
- Ref3: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Liquid_Si_-_Standard_MD

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer , so ENCUT will not change it will reamin constant as given in above  format of INCAR now question arises Which value should I set for ENCUT as Mg2Si converges at 700 eV or it will be  initial 500 eV for MD run?

Comment: @Shalini [grep ENMAX POTCAR] ==>  [ ENMAX  =  126.143; ENMIN  =   94.607 eV
   ENMAX  =  245.345; ENMIN  =  184.009 eV] I think ENCUT=400 is OK. Take a look at this: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ENCUT

Comment: Yes I think ENCUT =400 is OK or may be I can try for another values to see changes and what about temperature I mean how one will decide this temp. range for particular system lets say Mg2Si in my case  ? Thanks for discussion

Comment: @Shalini Temperature is decided by what you want to investigate.

Comment: Okay so energy convergence what should be range high or low ? I want to investigate simulation time vs ENCUT and KPOINTS .

Comment: @Shalini I think what you are asking is meaningless. ENCUT and KPOINTS should be fixed at convergence test. In general, people want to see energy versus time with different temperatures to investigate thermal stability.

Comment: @Shalini You may cite a related paper in your question.

Comment: I am sorry it was misprinting of temperature  but my question was that for energy convergence what should be temperature range for particular system high or low ? I want to investigate simulation time vs ENCUT and KPOINTS with Molecular Dynamics therefore how will I decide  different temperature for Mg2Si ?

Comment: I tried the above input file along with SOC, but my simulation stopped after one complete iteration. I am not getting why this is happening because I just added SOC in the above-described file. If anyone is familar with MD+SOC, please suggest.